# Printing my Program Output to a Single Line instead of on Multiple Lines

Tags: java

i want try get my system print out all on one line, example
"jack of hearts" 
"2 of clubs "
"ace of hearts"

i can get it to print out
"jack of
hearts "
some pointers would be a huge help, have only a few weeks experience with java, im using bluj to run and test

```
public class Cards {

    public static final int CARDS_IN_DECK = 52;
    public static final int SPADES = 0;
    public static final int HEARTS = 1;
    public static final int DIAMONDS = 2;
    public static final int CLUBS = 3;

    public static int deck[];  
    public static int deckSuit[];



    public static void main ()
    {

    {  int i; // counter
        int j;
        String value;

        createDeck();   // this is a function call

        // Show the cards in the deck
        System.out.println("Your hand is as follows:");
        for (i=0 ; i < 5; i++)
          // this is the loop for 5 card draw
         {

           if (deck[i]<=10 && deck[i]>1) // this is inbetween this range of numbers
              System.out.println(deck[i] + " of " + deckSuit[i]);

             if(deck[i]==11)
                System.out.println("jack" + " of " + deckSuit[i]);
            else if(deck[i]==12)
                System.out.println("queen" + " of " + deckSuit[i]);
            else if(deck[i]==13)
                System.out.println("king" + " of " + deckSuit[i]);
            else if(deck[i]==14)
                System.out.println("ace" + " of " + deckSuit[i]);

            if(deckSuit[i] == 0)
                System.out.println(" of " + "SPADES"); // i want to try and get a print out "jack of spades
             else if (deckSuit[i] == 1)
                System.out.println(" of " + "HEARTS");
             else if (deckSuit[i] == 2)
                System.out.println(" of " + "DIAMONDS");
             else if (deckSuit[i] == 3)
                System.out.println(" of " + "CLUBS");
                }
           }





    }

    // create the deck 
    //
    // deck[] contains the values of 52 cards
    // values 2 to 14
    // 2 - 10 are normal , 11 = Jack, 12 = Queen
    // 13 = King, 14 = Ace
    //
    // suit[] contains the values of the suits of the 52 cards
    // 0 Spades, 1 Hearts, 2 Diamonds, 3 Clubs
    //
    // so if deck[2] = 11 and suit[2] = 1
    // then that card would be the Jack of Hearts
    //     
    public static void createDeck()
    {
        int i,j, place;

        //

        //
        // create a deck of cards
        deck = new int[CARDS_IN_DECK];
        deckSuit = new int[CARDS_IN_DECK];
        // Populate the deck
        for (j=0; j<4 ; j++)    // the suits
        {
            for (i=2 ; i <= 14 ; i++) 
            // the cards
            {
                // find an empty place
                do
                {
                    place = (int)(Math.random()*CARDS_IN_DECK);     // 0 to 51             
                } while (deck[place] != 0);    
                deck[place] = i;    // store the card value
                deckSuit[place] = j;    // store the card suit
            }   }        }      

}
```

Comment: Yeah replace the println statements with just print

Comment: use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println` to prevent terminating lines between each call

Comment: Using arrays and primitive ints is not very Java way of doing it. Card and suites could be enums with overriden `toString()` methods - however that's just object oriented aesthetics. Oh, and do try to name your questions so that the title is a synopsis of your main problem.

Comment: I've changed the title to better reflect your question. The old one didn't explain the issue, and was open to misinterpretation given the meaning of "pointers" in other languages. Feel free to make any additional changes if I've misrepresented the issue.

Comment: @Deltharis the code posted is typically used in academic texts to teach the use of arrays. Although you are right about this being done better using an `enum`, you are missing the intent of the code (which is not about best practices).

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println` prints the output in the next line, use `System.out.print` to print on the same lines

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @TJ- OP asks how to print on the same line and Yusuf tells him that. How is this not an answer? This is not a detailed answer, but it is one.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `System.out.println` instead of `System.out.print`.